# Blazor: Access other object properties in bind:set and bind:after

Tags: asp.net, blazor, .net-7.0

I was curious to see new .net 7 Blazor binding syntax in action and tried to replace `@onchange="@(code => OnCodeChanged(code, r.ServiceId))"` with `bind:after` but I couldn't find a way to pass it ServiceId which I need to properly identify entity which is being updated.

Is there a way to pass arbitrary parameters to `bind:after` or `bind:set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```cs
@bind-value:set="(value) => this.OnChange(value, 1)"
```

but you can't do the same with `@bind-value:after` because of the way it's implemented.

See this answer to a recent question which goes into a little more detail and the current issues with the bind setup in Net7.0 -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277308/13065781.