# Blazor data binding: Set an input's @bind:set with a lambda Action

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I am following the [latest tutorial on data binding using @bind:get @bind:set modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-bindgetbindset-modifiers-and-avoid-event-handlers-for-two-way-data-binding) however a straight copy-paste of their *correct approach* example code results in an error on this line:

```
<input @bind:event="oninput" @bind:get="inputValue" @bind:set="OnInput" />
```

Which is:

```
CS1503 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<string>' to 'System.Action<string?>'
```

Is this is mistake in the Microsoft docs?

Comment: See this answer that explains things and why the SDK complained pre 7.0.4 SDK. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277308/13065781

Answer (score 1):

### Install the latest .NET SDK

I was missing a minor version update of the .NET 7 SDK