# Blazor run a function when InputSelect option is changed

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

i have ran into an issue while working in Blazor. I have an `InputSelect` field with a few options like this:

```
<InputSelect class="form-select" style="width:200px" @bind-Value="rotar1" @onchange="HandleRotar1Change">
                <option value="0">RotarI</option>
                <option value="1">RotarII</option>
                <option value="2">RotarIII</option>
                <option value="3">RotarIV</option>
                <option value="4">RotarV</option>
</InputSelect>
```

and below i have a function for the onchange

```
@code {
    int rotar1;
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        rotar1 = enigmaService.GetSelectedRotar(0);
    }

    
    private void HandleRotar1Change(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        
        int selectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
        enigmaService.SetRotar(0, selectedValue);
    }
  
}
```

However, the function never runs when i change an option. I have also tried `oninput` but that also doesnt work. Does anyone know how to get this working? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<InputSelect class="form-select"
             style="width:200px"
             TValue="int" 
             Value="rotar1"
             ValueChanged="HandleRotar1Change"
             ValueExpression="@(() => rotar1)">

    <option value="0">RotarI</option>
    <option value="1">RotarII</option>
    <option value="2">RotarIII</option>
    <option value="3">RotarIV</option>
    <option value="4">RotarV</option>
</InputSelect>

@code {
    int rotar1 = 3;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        rotar1 = enigmaService.GetSelectedRotar(0);
    }
    
    private void HandleRotar1Change(int selectedValue)
    {
        rotar1 = selectedValue;
        enigmaService.SetRotar(0, selectedValue);
    }
}
```

`@bind-Value` is like a shortcut for `Value`, `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression` parameters but you can pass them manually and call whatever else you need inside the `ValueChanged` callback.

Comment: Thanks that works, is there a way of passing another value to ValueChanged="HandleRotar1Change" as i want to pass the selectedValue and which rotar needs updating for example 0. I have tried ValueChanged="HandleRotar1Change(selectedvalue,0)" but that throws an error

Comment: You can use: `ValueChanged="selectedvalue => HandleRotar1Change(selectedvalue, 0)"`

Answer (score 0):

`@bind-Value="rotar1"` takes the `@onchange` during the Razor compiler binding process.  It ignores your directive.

You need to hook up to @bind-Value:after.

See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277308/13065781

And the MS docs article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0